# How to programmatically unlock the password protected onenote section using CSOM?

Tags: onenote

I'm building a Client Side Object Model(CSOM) solution using c# to re-create the problematic onenote section which is located within an onenote notebook. My code doesn't return the pages if my onenote section is password protected.

Once I unlocked the password from onenote2013 application, I'm able to view the total number of pages available under the sections. I googled a lot to find a way to unlock the password protection section using C#. But there is no luck.

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796230.aspx

Can anyone tell me whether there is a way to unlock the password protected section via C#?

Answer (score 0):

The OneNote REST API does not support password protected sections.